# ASP Classic: Is it possible for a VbScript function to return an object?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am learning VbScript and ASP Classic.

Is it possible for a VbScript function to return an object?

The code below is showing the following error on line 15:

Object doesn't support this property or method ('800a01b6' error)

```
<%
Class Customer
    Public Id
    Public Name
End Class

Class CustomerFactory
    Public Function GetCustomer()
        Dim cust
        Set cust = New Customer
        cust.Id = 1
        cust.Name = "Andrew"

        ' Return
        GetCustomer = cust
    End Function
End Class

Dim factory
Dim cust_from_factory

Set factory = New CustomerFactory
Set cust_from_factory = factory.GetCustomer()
%>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the cause of the error.

When returning the function, you must use the Set structure

Before (with error)

```
' Return
GetCustomer = cust
```

After

```
' Return
Set GetCustomer = cust
```